# PgAdmin4 - Data Output vazio

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, pgadmin

Instalei o PgAdmin 4 na minha maquina com windows 10 64bits, configurei o servidor, mas quando vou abrir alguma tabela a query parece executar normalmente, porém a aba de "Data Output" não mostra nada, nem colunas nem dados, fica tudo em branco.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Coloca um screenshot aí

Comment: Editei a pergunta com a imagem @rray

Comment: Se vc abrir a tabela para editar algum registro, aparecem as linhas?

Comment: nada, fica em branco tbm

Comment: Qual encoding do seu banco? tenta usar o comando `set encoding = 'LATIN1';` e depois executar a consulta... no lugar do LATIN1 pode ser UTF8, SQLASCII por exemplo, dependeria de como está configurado.